# Python on Mac OS X - opening and looking though CSV file

Tags: macos, python-2.7, csv

I am new to python and I want to write a script (on mac osx) that opens a csv file and then prints out the data.

This what I have thus far but it is not working? Is my syntax incorrect? see code

```
 import csv
 import os
 userhome = os.path.expanduser('~')
 csvfile= userhome + r'\Desktop\data.csv'
 open(csvfile, "r")
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is the error? Does the file exist?

Comment: The file exists and is located on my desktop. the error is this: OError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/DavidBailey\\Desktop\\data.csv' - is this not how you open a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python doesn't like the backward slashes in the path, which are used in Windows paths but not Mac paths.

The right way to fix it is to make the path platform-independent by building it with Python using [os.path.join()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```
import csv
import os.path

userhome = os.path.expanduser('~')
csvfile= os.path.join(userhome, 'Desktop', 'data.csv')
open(csvfile, "r")
```

Comment: @DavidBailey welcome to SO.  The best way to say "thanks" here is to upvote or accept an answer.